# Sync Git and web server

Tags: git, networking, version-control

I have a dedicated ubuntu based git server that my team using to collaborate building websites for our company.
Also I have a separate web server on a deferent machine.
My question is there any way to make the web server pulls from the master branch on the git server whenever a push action is made?
I figured out how to do so using git hooks if the git and web servers exist on the same machine.

Comment: You should catch the event that new changes are pushed to git server, and then develop the function to receive the information and take action (pull change to web server). Or an easier way is schedule to execute git pull on the web server (such as every 6 hours).

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the web server **pull** from the git server whenever a push happens unless the git server informs the web server first when a push happens.

If it is important that the web server do the pull, then define a special URL on the web server to notify it, and write a post-receive hook for the git server to do the notification.

Alternately, use the post-receive hook to push to the web server directly. This can be done with any program that can communicate over the network. Examples include an HTTP POST or scp or ftp.